# CPQ Javascript Quote Calculator Plugin Custom Script not updating

Tags: javascript, cpq, plugin-bug

I set up a simple CPQ Javascript Quote Calculator Plugin Custom Script last week and it was working fine.  Today, I wanted to update the script, but my changes don't seem to take effect.

My (simplified) custom script is as follows:

`export function onAfterCalculate(quote, lines, conn) {
  console.log('onAfterCalculate 4');
  return Promise.resolve();
}`

The name of the Custom Script is: SAPPricing.

In the CPQ Settings Editor -> Plugins -> Quote Calculator Plugin, I have specified the name of the Custom Script: SAPPricing.

However, when I run it, the Console Log outputs 'onAfterCalculate' which was specified in my previous version of this Custom Script.

I have tried running it in different browsers and I keep getting the output from the previous version of the script.  It seems like the old script is cached on the server and won't update.

Thoughts?

Mike

Update: I was able to modify it this morning, but after a couple of simple modifications, my updates to the Custom Script no longer are showing up when I perform calculate again.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen when there is an issue in the Javascript. CPQ transpiles the code you paste into the script. I've found that first pasting my plugin code into https://babeljs.io/repl and checking for errors, helps ensure there are no issues.

There is a field on the Custom Script object called **Transpiled Code**. You can also check that it gets updated after saving your changes.

Edit: There is a Visualforce page you can add to your Custom Script page layout called Custom Script Save. It will tell you the Transpiling status.

[image: page layout with VF page]

[image: transpiling status]

Comment: Thanks.  Have been using VS Code with the Salesforce CPQ - Quote Calculator Plugin and assuming that this would show any syntax errors.  Will also checking the Transpiled Code field to see if that correlates with code not getting updated.

Comment: Transpiled Code gives me a good view of whether my edits have been accepted or not.  However, if they haven't been accepted, I still have no other way to fix it except for cloning the Custom Script object.  Tried https://babeljs.io/repl on some code that was not transpiled, but it showed no errors.  Bottom line is I am still cloning Custom Script alot, but at least I have a work around.

Comment: I just found that there's a visualforce page you can add to your page layout that will tell you errors if there are any. Is that on your page layout?

Comment: Also you can try clearing the Transpiled Code field.

Comment: VF page is already on page layout. I turned on the label of VF Page to verify that it is there. Tried introducing error into my Javascript code intentionally and I do get an error similar to what you displayed. However, when I remove my intentional error, I get the same behavior I have been seeing - no error is displayed in VF Page, but it doesn't transpile either. If I save my code in classic, I can see VF Page briefly show the word "Transpiling" and then it completes without error, but transpiled code is not updated. Weird, because if I clone code to new record, it transpiles and runs fine.

Comment: One more thing to try is to delete the code, save, then add the code and save again. Maybe the change detection to see if the code field has changed they are using isn't always working correctly.

Comment: I think found the source of the issue.  I had a string surrounded by double quotes instead of single quotes.  This seems to only transpile on the initial clone, but fails to transpile (and doesn't throw a transpile error) upon updating.  Since I fixed this, it seems to be updating.  Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: Tip: Whenever I edit the Custom Script's Code field, I also clear out the Transpiled Code field (which we added to the Page Layout). After the save, the TC field displays blank whether or not the new code is OK. But refresh the page, and if the change is OK, the TC field will be filled again; if not, it will be empty. Also note: the VF page is not legible, at least in my system; but, if it isn't completely empty, on my system, there is an error in the code.

Comment: Also, https://babeljs.io/repl is a good way to test for many JS errors. But, babeljs.io accepts some code which SF doesn't accept.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to mention another sittuation when Transpiled Code is not generated - it's when "Disable Triggers" is checked in Salesforce CPQ configuration.

It also affects lists of referenced fields specified on Custom Script record by not being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only reliable way that I can make updates is to:

1. Clone the Custom Script.
2. In the in the CPQ Settings Editor -> Plugins -> Quote Calculator Plugin, specify the name of the cloned Custom Script.
3. Exit the Edit Lines window and navigate back in.

Directly editing the Custom Script works sometimes, but no reliably.

I have an open case with Salesforce, but no response from them yet.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I am had a similar problem. I copied the Code field into text files: from my sandbox,  from Production, and from an old sandbox.  The fc command (on a command line) revealed hidden characters at the ends of lines. The extra characters are always a Greek "tau" character and an accented lowercase "a" character. vscode does not display them nor does Notepad. I do not know how they got there. But copying code from Notepad into the Custom Script record's Code field using the SF Setup UI does not emplace the problem characters. Nor does editing directly into the Code field in the Setup UI. So I suspect that copying from vscode somehow inserted the bad characters.