# QCP - Not getting called

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins

I have created custom script in which i have added following code :

```
export function onAfterCalculate(quoteModel, quoteLineModels){
console.log('quote is called');
return Promise.resolve();
};
```

name of the script is : TestScript

I have added this name in configuration of installed package - > Steelbrick configuration- >plugin - > Quote Calculator Plugin - > TestScript

But i am not able to see any debug log after calculation.

how to call that custom script? am i doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [similar post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246442/cpq-javascript-quote-calculator-plugin-custom-script-not-updating) that was discussed a year ago

If it doesn't help raise it again with a proper note